# How to disable screen snip in notification area?

Tags: windows, capture

I am developing a capture preventing software, but I can not prevent capturing by using screen snip in notification area (at Windows 10 1909).
I want to disable it.
How to disable screen snip in notification area programmatically?
Please help me.

Comment: Do you want to prevent any screen capture to capture your own app, or do you just want the screen snip to be unavailable when your app is active?

Comment: I just want only the screen snip to be disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the screen snip invisible in the notification area by adding a new value to the registry.

Run regedit.exe and add a new value called *Microsoft.QuickAction.ScreenClipping* under *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Quick Actions\Control Center\Unpinned*.

The value type is *REG_BINARY* and value data does not need to be set.

Then you can see that the screen snip has disappeared in the notification area.